# Topbar off center?

Tags: css, html, center

I have a div that I'm using as a topbar with the code below:

```
#topbar {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #336680;
    box-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.1em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I'm trying to make it go across the whole screen but for some reason it's off center and doesnt cover the left portion of the screen. How do I fix this?

Comment: By adding `left: 0`....

Comment: oh thanks I don't know why I didn't try that haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `left:0`. So...

```
#topbar {
height: 40px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #336680;
box-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.1em;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
padding: 0;
left:0;
}
```